# Grouping similar items in a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

**Task**
I am making a research project tracker in excel which my team will need to fill out.

To make the tracker easier to fill in I gave some of the columns a drop down multi-select functionality which means some cells will have more than one response in them (e.g., methodology).
This is what the raw data looks like:

[image: Example Raw Data]

I would like to see a breakdown of the different types of research projects which have been run across the year.

To do this I have created some pivot tables and linked them to the charts.

However, I have encountered an issue where the pivot table shows a break-down of the combinations of multi-select responses rather than counting the frequency of each individual item.

For example, when breaking down the data by research methodology my current pivot table looks like this:

| research_methodology | count |
| --- | --- |
| Interview | 1 |
| Survey | 1 |
| Card Sort | 1 |
| Interview, survey | 2 |

Instead, I would like it to separate out the interview, survey combination and count each methodology separately. So it looks like this:

| research_methodology | count |
| --- | --- |
| Interview | 3 |
| Survey | 3 |
| Card Sort | 1 |

**Requirements**

This tracker will be used regularly by my team so I would like the pivot tables I create to automatically update as people add to the tracker. This should be a dynamic and easy to use document!

The raw data in the tracker contains at least 5 columns that I would like to have this functionality and may have up to 20 different multi-select options.

**Question**

Does anyone know how to approach my request? If this is even possible on Excel!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**My attempts**

1. I have tried using countif and wildcard statements but they are not suitable for what I am doing as I would need to use the filters associated with the pivot tables I have created (e.g. I need to be able to filter by date, if I use COUNTIF it won't capture the date).
2. I don't think Power query is suitable as there are so many columns and potential selections that the transformations won't be practical (I could be wrong though!).
3. I think my best bet is updating VBA to influence how pivot tables process data, instructing it to group categories with similar names.
   Assuming I need to write separate code for each pivot table on the sheet I wrote some code including the following parameters...

(sheet name = project_summary_data; pivot table name = PivotTable14; pivot table field= research_method.

Here is the code I pasted into VBA for the project_summary_data sheet; however it keeps giving me a 400 error code.

```
Sub GroupSimilarItemsInPivotTable()
    ' Set the worksheet containing the pivot table
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets("project_summary_data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet 'project_summary_data' not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set the pivot table
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable14")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If pt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "PivotTable 'PivotTable14' not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set the pivot field containing the multi-select options
    Dim pf As PivotField
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("research_method")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If pf Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "PivotField 'research_method' not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Initialize a collection to store grouped items
    Dim groupedItems As Collection
    Set groupedItems = New Collection
    
    ' Loop through each item in the pivot field
    Dim item As PivotItem
    For Each item In pf.PivotItems
        ' Check if the item has already been grouped
        If Not IsInCollection(groupedItems, item.Name) Then
            ' Add the item to the grouped items collection
            groupedItems.Add item.Name
            
            ' Loop through the remaining items to find similar names
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = item.Position + 1 To pf.PivotItems.Count
                If InStr(pf.PivotItems(i).Name, item.Name) > 0 Then
                    ' Update the item name to include the additional option
                    item.Name = item.Name & ", " & pf.PivotItems(i).Name
                    ' Add the count of the additional item to the original item
                    item.DataRange.Value = item.DataRange.Value + pf.PivotItems(i).DataRange.Value
                    ' Delete the additional item
                    pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next item
    
    MsgBox "Code execution completed successfully."
End Sub
```

---

```
Function IsInCollection(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsInCollection = Not col(key) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: IMHO your tracker is ambiguos. What does the first line mean? Fred used interview, Harry used survey or did Fred use a survey and interview and Harry used interview.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [PowerQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/) to do this job.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblData"]}[Content],
    changeType1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type datetime}, {"Project Name", type text}, {"Product area", type text}, {"Researcher", type text}, {"Research Methodology", type text}}),
    separate = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(changeType1, {{"Research Methodology", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Research Methodology"),
    changeType2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(separate,{{"Research Methodology", type text}}),
    properCase = Table.TransformColumns(changeType2,{{"Research Methodology", Text.Proper, type text}}),
    clean = Table.TransformColumns(properCase,{{"Research Methodology", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    group = Table.Group(clean, {"Research Methodology"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    group
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use VBA and a dictionary to do the math

```
 Option Explicit

Sub useDictionary()
    Const COMMA = ","
    
    ' Data is an table with the name tblData
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = shData.ListObjects("tblData")

    ' Dictionary will store the information on the Project Methodology and count
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' 5th column contains the information on Project Methodology
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(5)


    Dim vdat As Variant, item As Variant
    vdat = rg
        
    For Each item In vdat
        If InStr(1, item, COMMA) Then
            Dim v As Variant, i As Long
            ' If value contains a COMMA then split and add the information to the dictionary
            v = Split(item, COMMA)
            For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                v(i) = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(v(i)))
                dict(v(i)) = dict(v(i)) + 1
            Next i
        Else
            ' no split neccessary
            item = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim(item))
            dict(item) = dict(item) + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' Write output
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    
    Set rg = Range("A1")
    Set rg = rg.Resize(dict.Count, 2)
    rg.Columns(1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    rg.Columns(2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)

End Sub
```

I here take advantage of the fact that `dict(Key) = Value` will change the value at the key resp. will automatically add if the key does not exist.